# hide field in Power BI table visual

Tags: powerbi

I have a power bi table visual where I use a field to sort the table, is it possible to keep the field for sort purpose but not showing that field/column
in the visual?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
[image]

In this example column breadth is sorted by column Length but Length is not shown in Table visual.